# Default method arguments don't work

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

Cython doesn't seem to recognize, that the `sf::RenderTarget.clear()` method can be called with different arguments and allows to call only the last declared variant in .pxd.

SFML's header file ([source](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp)):

```
class RenderTarget {
    void clear(const Color& color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
}
```

My Cython .pxd:

```
cdef extern from 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' namespace 'sf' nogil:
    cppclass CRenderTarget 'sf::RenderTarget':
        void clear()
        void clear(const CColor&)

    cppclass CRenderWindow 'sf::RenderWindow' (CWindow, CRenderTarget):
        ...
```

My Cython wrapper:

```
cdef class RenderWindow(Window):
    cdef CWindow* c

    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.c = new CRenderWindow()
        ...

    def clear(self, Color color=None):
        if color is None:
            (<CRenderWindow*>self.c).clear()  # The error points here
        else:
            (<CRenderWindow*>self.c).clear(color.c[0])
```

Compilation error: `Call with wrong number of arguments (expected 1, got 0)`

So I can call only whe `.clear(color)` variant and not the one with a default argument `.clear()`. What I'm doing wrong?

My implementation tries to follow what is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081678/handling-default-parameters-in-cython), but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Why don't you try .clear(None) for the first case ? And btw render target has no definition of the color variant ? And I don't understand why you'd have to make two functions if you already have a default argument in case color is none.

Comment: Caliing `.clear(None)` doesn't compile unfortunately. And I'm not making two functions, they are defined in SFML's source code and I'm trying to make a wrapper for them to be able to call them from Python.

Comment: Does the order that you list the `clear` functions matter (in your pxd file)?

Comment: @DavidW It seems that only the last function defined in pxd works (is visible to Cython).

Comment: Very similar code is translated correctly for me (on Cython 0.25.1). It might be worth checking your Cython version - if it's lower then upgrade and if it's higher then file a bug report.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for suggestion, but I'm already using v0.25.2. And I've found probably a related issue: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1374

Comment: It'd probably still be a good idea for you to file a bug report - this looks a regression given that it works on a lower version and so hopefully it should be readily fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given aliases ([C names](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications)) for methods in similar situations. In this case

```
cdef extern from 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' namespace 'sf' nogil:
    cppclass CRenderTarget 'sf::RenderTarget':
        void clear0 "clear" ()
```

Comment: I think you've got it the wrong way round here - `void clear0 "clear"()`? So that they both refer to the C++ `clear` but Cython thinks they have different names.

Comment: Yes, I'm now using aliases in my code, as you've proposed. I've also found a bug report, probably related: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1374